# ApexTest Class Coverage

Tags: unit-test

I need **100% code coverage** of Below ApexClass. My test class covers only 66% please help to sort out.

```
public with sharing class Accountcontactpicklist 
{
    public String selectedAccId{get;set;}
    public String selectedConId{get;set;}

          public List<SelectOption> getAccountNames()
           {
                  List<SelectOption> accOptions= new List<SelectOption>();
                  accOptions.add( new SelectOption('','--Select--'));
                  for( Account acc : [select Id,name from Account where name like '[abc]%' limit 5 ] ) 
                  {
                          accOptions.add( new SelectOption(acc.Id,acc.name));
                  }

                 return accOptions;
           }

           public List<SelectOption> getContactNames() 
           {

                  List<SelectOption> conOptions= new List<SelectOption>();
                  List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
                    if(selectedAccId != null)
                    {     
                       for( contact con : [select Id,name,accountid from contact where accountid=:selectedAccId ] ) 
                       {
                          conOptions.add( new SelectOption(con.Id,con.name));
                       }
                    }                  
                    else
                    {
                        conOptions.add( new SelectOption('--None--','--None--'));
                    }
                 return conOptions;
           }
    }
```

THIS IS MY TEST CLASS

```
@isTest
public with sharing class TestAccContPick 
{
    static testmethod void testAccConPlist()
    {
        contact con = new contact();
        con.LastName = 'Bonsy';
        con.password__c = 'abc';
        insert con;

        account acc = new account();
        acc.name = 'Bhupinder';
        insert acc;
        account acc1 = new account();
        acc1.name = 'Rahul';
        insert acc1;

        Accountcontactpicklist acp = new Accountcontactpicklist();
        acp.getAccountNames();
        acp.getContactNames();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to satisfy the condition i.e `if(selectedAccId != null)` so when you first time call `getContactNames()`,  `selectedAccId` value is null so else part covered.

Now just set the `selectedAccId` value and again call the `getContactNames()` method.

```
 Accountcontactpicklist acp = new Accountcontactpicklist();
 acp.getAccountNames();
 acp.getContactNames();
 acp.selectedAccId  = acc1.Id; 
 acp.getContactNames();
```

After that put some `system.assert` to check expected value

Comment: Thanks but Only cover 83 Percentage.

Comment: @Bonny you need to set this `selectedConId` value as well

Comment: @isTest
public with sharing class TestAccContPick 
{
 static testmethod void testAccConPlist()
    {
        contact con = new contact();
        con.LastName = 'Bonsy';
        con.password__c = 'abc';
        insert con;
       
        account acc = new account();
        acc.name = 'abc';
        insert acc;
       
        
        Accountcontactpicklist acp = new Accountcontactpicklist();
        acp.getAccountNames();
        acp.getContactNames();
        acp.selectedAccId  = acc.Id; 
        acp.selectedConId = con.Id;
        acp.getContactNames();
    }
}